# text-decoration: line-through double; not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

**text-decoration: line-through double;** not working in chrome browser.
is any other option to get double strikethrough?

```html
<h2 style="text-decoration: line-through double;">Hello</h2>
```

Comment: What you mean? please describe what is the issue.

Comment: @AlonEitan Thank you too gever gever

Comment: guys.. line-through double not working in chrome browser.. how can i get it.??

Comment: Since there is no _double_ value for `text-decoration`, post the html/css you have so far, and preferable a drawing, showing exactly how you want it to look like

Comment: @LGSon. that's the issue. it's working in firebox.not working in chrome

Comment: @AlonEitan good fun. please check it now.

Comment: That only works in Firefox, there is no standard for the other browsers

Comment: @LIJINSAMUEL please check this post firebox and chorme

Comment: @LGSon ok. is there any option to get double strike in chrome?

Comment: Please check following link https://fiddle.jshell.net/Lvrg9Lpg/

Comment: @vedankitakumbhar great. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also try this

```css
h2{position:relative;display:inline-block;}
h2:before, h2:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background: #000;
    top: 44%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
h2:after{
  top:55%;
  }
```

```html
<h2>Hello</h2>
```

Answer (score 4):

There is no standard for adding double lines. An option would be to use a pseudo element.

```css
.doublestrike {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.doublestrike::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 45%;
  height: 10%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-width: 1px 0;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="doublestrike">Hello</h2>
```

Comment: @PaulAnburaj You're welcome. May I ask why you changed the accepted answer?